# sfWidgetFormInputText weird behaviour

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Well, I have this form:

```
class CaracteristicaForm extends sfForm {

    public function configure() {

        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'caracteristica' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default'=>'hola mundo'))
        ));

        $this->setValidators(array(
            'caracteristica' => new sfValidatorString(
                array(
                    'max_length' => 150,
                    'required' => true
                )
            )
        ));

        $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

    }

}
```

and then I try to...

```
$form = new CaracteristicaForm();
$this->embedForm('caracteristica', $form);
```

but **the rendered inputText does not have any value at all**.

What am I missing?

Ok, to reproduce this you need to embed this form into another form (mine is a Doctrine child form) so maybe is something about some method changing the value?

Well, passing an array defaults did the trick:

```
$form = new CaracteristicaForm(array('caracteristica' => $caracteristica));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try to

```
$form->setDefault('caracteristica', $caracteristica);
```

in action?